# How does the blocking FET Q1 exactly work in this case?

Tags: mosfet, charging, wireless-charging

[image]This is a wireless power controller chip. Means it is a controller that switches between a wired (5 V) USB supply and a wireless power supply based on availability and also based on priority. In the page no. 35 of its datasheet [bq51013b](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq51013b.pdf?ts=1620649914948&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), it is mentioned that the blocking FET Q1 is used in the configuration. So the power controller is not being used at all when the wired supply is detected? Somebody please break down this P-MOSFET combination.

Comment: google `mosfet body diode`

Answer (score 0):

> So the power controller is not being used at all when the wired supply
> is detected?

When the controller detects a wired power supply it stops receiving wireless power and turns on the FET, so it is 'being used' only to keep the FET turned on.

The FET actually consists of two FETs wired 'back-to-back' to prevent current flowing through the body diode from the system back into the wired supply if it is a lower voltage or is itself a load (which is only permitted in [USB On-The-Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) mode).